# Check if QFont is Serif or Sans-Serif

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

I have a QFont selected by the user:

```
QFont font = QFontDialog::getFont(&ok, prevFont, this);
```

How do I know if it is a serif font or not?

Comment: Did you check QFont attributes?

Comment: Which function do I use to do that? Sans Serif is mentioned only in conjunction with the `styleHint` property, but there it is a hint for the font matching algorithm. However, my font is already chosen.

Comment: Do you need this to work for all platforms, or one in particular (Windows, Mac, Linux)? I don't think you can get this information from Qt directly, but there may be a non-portable way, like getting the `LOGFONT` structure from the `HFONT` handle on Windows.

Comment: I needs to work on Windows only.

Comment: Tests demonstrate that querying the `styleHint` either via the `QFont` itself or through a `QFontInfo` does not work. The style hint is for outgoing font matching only and will not reflect the properties of the actual system font that is loaded. They are used as a guide by Qt to identify the best candidate font. I could be wrong but I doubt there is any inherent serif indicator in a font file other than that text occurring in the font name.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
bool isSansSerrif = (font.styleHint() & QFont::SansSerif);
bool isSerrif = (font.styleHint() & QFont::Serif);
```