# Finding if QFont is serif, sanserif, monospaced..... and maybe code page

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, qt

I found this [Check if QFont is Serif or Sans-Serif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570288/check-if-qfont-is-serif-or-sans-serif) but it doesn't answer the question.

I use QT on Windows, Linux, and MacOS. When a user selects a font, I need to know if the font is serif, sans serif, proportional, or monospaced (and codepage). I moved from WxWidgets, which gave me that information, to Qt, which does not.

Is there a way, even OS specific (for all 3 OS's) that I can find that information out?

Comment: In what way does the [link you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570288/check-if-qfont-is-serif-or-sans-serif) *not* provide the information you need?  The [style hints](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#StyleHint-enum) appear to provide the required details.

Comment: StyleHints doesn't work. If called on a QFont or a QFontInfo, it returns only what was set by the user for the font matching engine, not what the font actually is. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontinfo.html#styleHint and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#styleHint Also see Arnold Spence's comment. As for going directly to the underlying OS, see the final line on my question above.